# How can I format UTCTime / NominalDiffTime into a human readable representation?

Tags: haskell

I've tried googling about but struggling to find a concrete example or which libraries I should be using for this.

I'd like to format a value of type `NominalDiffTime` ([NominalDiffTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.8.0.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime)) for example as `05/10/2017 10:10AM`.

Comment: I recommend [the `thyme` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thyme-0.3.5.5/docs/Data-Thyme-Format-Human.html).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, `thyme` hasn't been updated on Hackage since 2014.

Comment: @dfeuer Hm yeah, pity. Probably better use some lenses on top of old `time` then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I think there is some confusion because of the type alias: `type POSIXTime = NominalDiffTime` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.8.0.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html#t:POSIXTime).

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Format
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

myFormatUtcTime :: UTCTime -> String
myFormatUtcTime = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M %d/%m/%Y"

myFormatDiffTime :: NominalDiffTime -> String
myFormatDiffTime = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M" . posixSecondsToUTCTime
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [`fmt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fmt) library for time formatting.

1. Human-readable names of functions instead of some strange formatting symbols sometimes.
2. It can format not only time.

Example here:

```
ghci> import Data.Time (getZonedTime)
ghci> import Fmt.Time (dateDashF, dateSlashF)
ghci> t <- getZonedTime 
ghci> t
2017-10-05 14:53:08.818531 MSK
it :: ZonedTime
ghci> dateDashF t
"2017-10-05"
it :: Data.Text.Internal.Builder.Builder 
ghci> dateSlashF t
"10/05/17"
it :: Data.Text.Internal.Builder.Builder
```